# Ubuntu 20.04: Grub Menu Not Visible after Update from 19.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, 19.10

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 after updating from Ubuntu 19.10. After updating and restarting the computer, the screen is blank but I am still able to select the options from the menu so I know it is there.

I have tried reinstalling grub2 and changing the grub theme but the problem still persists.

Any other possible solution that would make the grub menu visible again?

Answer (score 0):

try ESC button to show menu, but be quick

Comment: This does not work for me. No changes.